# Recursively determine cubic spline coefficients

Tags: recursive-algorithms, spline

I am looking for a way to fit a cubic spline on previously recorded points without using matrices. The software is running on an embedded microcontroller which is low on RAM, so calculating my coefficients (at least 18points, double precision) the way it is described [here](https://timodenk.com/blog/cubic-spline-interpolation/) or [here](https://www.value-at-risk.net/cubic-spline-interpolation/) is probably not feasible. Is there a way to determine the coefficients recursively (e.g. segment by segment), so that I can avoid inverting 68x68 matrix (for 18pts/17 segments)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [centripetal Catmull-Rom spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_Catmull%E2%80%93Rom_spline) to create the spline that  interpolate all the data points without matrix inversion.

Comment: Thank you, it is not trivial, but it seems to work for me.